# Confusion over correct answer. How should I proceed?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, downvotes, specific-answer

There is a lot of confusion surrounding this post.
[Multiple bash commands in background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36846993/multiple-bash-commands-in-background/)

The question and answers all have downvotes now.   Admittedly the behaviour of `ffmpeg` in this situation is contrary to expectations, but I know my answer is correct because I verified it *before* submitting it. The OP knows it is correct because he accepted the answer.

To clarify, if you try to run ffmpeg in the background without redirecting its output, it will suspend. This was difficult for the OP to debug since he was calling it from php exec(). Of course he neglected to mention that at the time. I edited the post for him today, but didn't have those privileges at first.

I'm tempted to just delete my answer, since it is the only post i have ever made that was not well received, but it *is* the most correct answer.

Walking away is another good option I suppose. I'm not going to lose much sleep either way but am interested to hear what people think.

Comment: I expect that the downvotes are coming due being OT.

Comment: No, people aren't morons, they just see a not-so-good question and downvote whatever they see surrounding it, including answers.

Comment: not sure what you mean by OT?

Comment: OT means off-topic...

Comment: Sorry, still have no idea what you mean. Does the question not *define* the topic?

Comment: @Braiam What about it is off topic? Now that the question has all the details, it seems to be an ok, but low quality question.

Comment: @Laurel I agree the question is not exactly high quality. My answer is also in need of refactoring now that the question has been altered, but since its difficult to discuss a moving target I will delay the edit until I gather some opinions here.

Comment: I can add all the details about the sickness of my cat, but that doesn't mean that the question is on topic

Comment: and it is off topic because ... ?

Comment: @Braiam Can you just explain why you think *the post in question* is off-topic? We're not looking for a comprehensive definition of off-topic...

Comment: ok I went and read the help on off-topic. "a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development" seems to cover this question pretty well.

Comment: @user6170930 You only cite the further restriction. Still, it fits "•a specific programming problem; ...; and is [your quote here]". Cross-referencing the "don't ask"-[help/dont-ask] page, we stay with perfectly on-topic.

Comment: extensive chat session in the comments kind of proves it is a crap question and will be totally useless to anyone in the future, because you have to read the entire comment exchange to get something of an answer

Comment: That was my rationale for amending the question and answer. The only real information in the entire page is that "ffmpeg will automatically suspend if it doesn't have access to standard out." That little tit-bit might be of use to someone. It is *no longer necessary* to read any of the comments in order to understand the question or the answer. The initial downvote to the accepted answer came from the third party in the comments who was angry at being wrong. If you think the question should be removed then I won't object. I stand by the quality of my other posts and have done my best here.

Comment: @Jarrod Just to be clear, If the consensus here had been that the question was OT or unsuitable in any way, and that deleting an *accepted* answer is an appropriate act in that situation, then I would immediately have done so. Currently doing so would only make the page worse, since then we would be left with a *wrong* answer to a *poor* question. The purpose of the meta question was to get advice, not to defend one position or the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The consensus seems to be that the question is of low quality but *is* in fact on-topic. So I will edit my answer to address the updated version of the question.

Then I will let it sit, and try to have faith that its rating will eventually adjust to reflect its correctness.

Comment: Immediately after my edit, it got flagged for deletion. o.O  Time to throw in the towel I suppose.

Comment: That could be the Meta effect...

Comment: Could be. Still the Meta Effect has been *very* kind to me this week from my one other meta post, so I can't complain :)